# how to connect trust wallet and metamask in react with ethers.js

Tags: reactjs, mobile, wallet, decentralized-applications

I am going to connect with trust wallet on mobile and metamask on computer in react.
but now I can only connect with metamask. I want to connect with trust wallet on mobile.
How does it solve?

Comment: I'm waiting for react library for multiple wallet connector supported.

Answer (score 0):

use WalletConnect in [web3-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-react) or [web3Modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3modal)

you can read the documentation from [coinbase wallet sdk](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/web3-react)

Comment: I recommend using Web3.JS lib because these 2 libs you mentioned are outdated and no longer maintained.